# How to disable press power button twice for camera programmatically

Tags: camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

Nexus 5X, Nexus 6P and Android 6.0.1 offer a shortcut to launch the camera by pressing twice on the device power button.
There is a way to disable this shortcut manually in:

1. Settings
2. Display
3. Switch off the "Press power button twice for camera" option.

Is there a way to disable this service programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In Android 7.1, this feature is located under "Moves (Quick gestures to control your phone)" in Settings.

Comment: Thanks but what about doing this programmatically?